# replace all numeric characters in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, str-replace, replaceall

What better way to replace all numeric characters in google sheets?

I tried the following way but it takes a long time to run and it doesn't look professional:

```
var caracteres = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", ",", "|", ";", ".", "-" ]
  for(c=0; c<caracteres.length; c++){
    sheet.getRange("E:E").createTextFinder(caracteres[c]).replaceAllWith("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer have to loop so it saves a lot of time.

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange("E1:E" + sh.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("[0-9,;|.-]+").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('');
}
```